# Download document library from Windows SharePoint Services 3.0

Tags: sharepoint-server

I just started with this company and they have a legacy Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 server. I need to grab the entire contents of the document libraries from the site. Can anyone point me to a resource or method to pull this data? When I try to open explorer view it says all the available browsers are unsupported. I've tried using explorer with different accounts, including the sharepoint administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Click the settings cog
2. Click "Compatibility View Settings"
3. Tick the radio button for "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View"

Also check if `WebClient` service is running on your client.